# "Missing INTERNET PERMISSION" and EACCESS denied " in spite adding user-permissions in android manifest file?

Tags: android

```
java.lang.SecurityException: Permission denied (missing INTERNET permission?)
04-09 12:56:46.050 22026-22463/com.example.android.newsapp W/System.err:     at java.net.InetAddress.lookupHostByName(InetAddress.java:451)
04-09 12:56:46.050 22026-22463/com.example.android.newsapp W/System.err:     at java.net.InetAddress.getAllByNameImpl(InetAddress.java:252)
04-09 12:56:46.050 22026-22463/com.example.android.newsapp W/System.err:     at java.net.InetAddress.getAllByName(InetAddress.java:215)
04-09 12:56:46.051 22026-22463/com.example.android.newsapp W/System.err:     at com.android.okhttp.HostResolver$1.getAllByName(HostResolver.java:29)
04-09 12:56:46.051 22026-22463/com.example.android.newsapp W/System.err:     at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.RouteSelector.resetNextInetSocketAddress(RouteSelector.java:232)
04-09 12:56:46.051 22026-22463/com.example.android.newsapp W/System.err:     at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.RouteSelector.next(RouteSelector.java:124)
04-09 12:56:46.051 22026-22463/com.example.android.newsapp W/System.err:     at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.HttpEngine.connect(HttpEngine.java:274)
04-09 12:56:46.051 22026-22463/com.example.android.newsapp W/System.err:     at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.HttpEngine.sendRequest(HttpEngine.java:213)
04-09 12:56:46.051 22026-22463/com.example.android.newsapp W/System.err:     at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.HttpURLConnectionImpl.execute(HttpURLConnectionImpl.java:373)
04-09 12:56:46.051 22026-22463/com.example.android.newsapp W/System.err:     at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.HttpURLConnectionImpl.connect(HttpURLConnectionImpl.java:106)
04-09 12:56:46.051 22026-22463/com.example.android.newsapp W/System.err:     at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.HttpURLConnectionImpl.getOutputStream(HttpURLConnectionImpl.java:208)
04-09 12:56:46.051 22026-22463/com.example.android.newsapp W/System.err:     at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.DelegatingHttpsURLConnection.getOutputStream(DelegatingHttpsURLConnection.java:218)
04-09 12:56:46.051 22026-22463/com.example.android.newsapp W/System.err:     at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.HttpsURLConnectionImpl.getOutputStream(HttpsURLConnectionImpl.java:25)
04-09 12:56:46.051 22026-22463/com.example.android.newsapp W/System.err:     at com.example.android.newsapp.RequestHandler.sendPostRequest(RequestHandler.java:60)
04-09 12:56:46.051 22026-22463/com.example.android.newsapp W/System.err:     at com.example.android.newsapp.MainActivity$1UploadImage.doInBackground(MainActivity.java:114)
04-09 12:56:46.051 22026-22463/com.example.android.newsapp W/System.err:     at com.example.android.newsapp.MainActivity$1UploadImage.doInBackground(MainActivity.java:88)
04-09 12:56:46.051 22026-22463/com.example.android.newsapp W/System.err:     at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:288)
04-09 12:56:46.051 22026-22463/com.example.android.newsapp W/System.err:     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:237)
04-09 12:56:46.051 22026-22463/com.example.android.newsapp W/System.err:     at android.os.AsyncTask$SerialExecutor$1.run(AsyncTask.java:231)
04-09 12:56:46.051 22026-22463/com.example.android.newsapp W/System.err:     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1112)
04-09 12:56:46.051 22026-22463/com.example.android.newsapp W/System.err:     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:587)
04-09 12:56:46.051 22026-22463/com.example.android.newsapp W/System.err:     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:818)
04-09 12:56:46.051 22026-22463/com.example.android.newsapp W/System.err: Caused by: android.system.GaiException: android_getaddrinfo failed: EAI_NODATA (No address associated with hostname)
04-09 12:56:46.055 22026-22463/com.example.android.newsapp W/System.err:     at libcore.io.Posix.android_getaddrinfo(Native Method)
04-09 12:56:46.056 22026-22463/com.example.android.newsapp W/System.err:     at libcore.io.ForwardingOs.android_getaddrinfo(ForwardingOs.java:55)
04-09 12:56:46.056 22026-22463/com.example.android.newsapp W/System.err:     at java.net.InetAddress.lookupHostByName(InetAddress.java:438)
04-09 12:56:46.056 22026-22463/com.example.android.newsapp W/System.err:    ... 21 more
04-09 12:56:46.056 22026-22463/com.example.android.newsapp W/System.err: Caused by: android.system.ErrnoException: android_getaddrinfo failed: EACCES (Permission denied)
04-09 12:56:46.056 22026-22463/com.example.android.newsapp W/System.err:    ... 24 more
```

Here is the manifest file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="com.example.android.newsapp">
<user-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_WIFI_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CHANGE_WIFI_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CHANGE_NETWORK_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:supportsRtl="true"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
    <activity android:name=".MainActivity">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <!-- ATTENTION: This was auto-generated to add Google Play services to your project for
         App Indexing.  See https://g.co/AppIndexing/AndroidStudio for more information. -->
    <meta-data
        android:name="com.google.android.gms.version"
        android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version" />
</application>

</manifest>
```

I viewed some answers on the same error but all said to add INTERNET/ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE permission outside application tag.
I did so but nothing worth happened.
While debugging I found that in the sendPostRequest Method it don't goes to try block but goes to catch block directly.

Comment: I am new in stackoverflow can you tell why question is downvoted?

Comment: You are using the network fine... The error clearly says `No address associated with hostname`, which means your DNS request has failed.

Comment: when you ask question related to android permissions, please also post your manifest.xml

Comment: You need to understand how networking works... It means that whatever URL you use, say stackoverflow.com, cannot be looked up in the public database of valid URLs and assigned an IP address, which is actually what is used to send a network request

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You must use

```xml
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
```

instead of

```xml
<user-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
```